# ERROR in ngrx createSelector TypeError: Cannot read property 'isOpen' of undefined

Tags: angular, ngrx

I am using the createSelector function

I have this problem that I could not solve, and I have reached a point that I do not know what to do

```
export const getRecoveryIsOpen = createSelector(
    getRecoveryPasswordState,
    fromRecoveryPassword.getRecoveryPasswordIsOpen
)
```

So I invoke her

```
this.store.select(reducers.getRecoveryState).subscribe( isBlur => {
    console.log(isBlur)
})
```

Pero siempre me sale el mismo error al momento de cargar la pagina. y en el Redux devtools estan los estados cargados correctamente

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'isOpen' of undefined
    at getRecoveryPasswordIsOpen (recovery-password.reducer.ts:65)
    at store.js:938
    at memoized (store.js:853)
    at defaultStateFn (store.js:893)
    at store.js:947
    at memoized (store.js:853)
    at MapSubscriber.project (store.js:772)
    at MapSubscriber._next (map.js:29)
    at MapSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
    at MapSubscriber._next (map.js:35)
```

this is my recovery-password.reducer

```
import * as RecoveryPasswordActions from '../actions/recovery-password.actions';
import { RecoveryPasswordActionTypes } from '../actions/recovery-password.actions';


export interface State {
    identificacion: number;
    error: String;
    currentStep: number;
    isOpen: boolean;
}

const initialState: State = {
    identificacion: null,
    error: "",
    currentStep: 1,
    isOpen: false
}

export function RecoveryPasswordReducer(state: State = initialState, action: RecoveryPasswordActions.actions) {

    switch (action.type) {
        case RecoveryPasswordActionTypes.OpenRecoveryPassword:
            return {
                ...state,
                isOpen: true
            }

        case RecoveryPasswordActionTypes.CloseRecoveryPassword:
            return {
                ...state,
                isOpen: false
            }

        case RecoveryPasswordActionTypes.SendIdUser:
            return {
                ...state,
                identificacion: action.payload.identificacion
            }

        case RecoveryPasswordActionTypes.SendIdUserError:
            return {
                ...state,
                error: action.payload.error
            }

        case RecoveryPasswordActionTypes.SendIdUserSuccess:
            return {
                ...state,
                currentStep: 2
            }

        case RecoveryPasswordActionTypes.SendRecoveryMethod:
            return {
                ...state,
                recoveryMethod: action.payload.recoveryMethod
            }

        default:
            return state;
    }

}

export const getRecoveryPasswordState = (state: State) => state;
export const getRecoveryPasswordIsOpen = (state: State) => state.isOpen;
export const getRecoveryPasswordCurrentStep = (state: State) => state.currentStep;
export const getRecoveryPasswordError = (state: State) => state.error;
```

I have reviewed a lot and I really don't find any mistakes, I would like to know if I am doing something wrong.

Comment: A part of your question is in spanish please note that this is an english site

Answer (score 1):

```
export const selectIsOpen = createFeatureSelector<boolean>('isOpen'); // if you dont have any name for module AppModule or this is not Child StroreModule
export const selectPatent = createFeatureSelector<State>('Parent name'); // parent name you can find in parant Module in imports StoreModule.forFeature('Parent name', reducers)
export const export const getRecoveryIsOpen = createSelector(selectPatent, (state) => state && state.isOpen);
```